# is it possible to use photobucket api in my rails application for twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, photobucket

I am wondering if its possible to use photobucket api in my rails twitter application to
upload photos.

is there any gem to do this or i need to do it by digging through Photobucket?

Please suggest.

Comment: Normally these kinds of questions are migrated to StackOverflow. But due to its low quality nature they will close it as soon as they receive it so I am just going to close it here.